Java Array behaving as call-by-reference only sometimes
I've encountered an interesting issue in Java - I don't know if it's a well known thing (I don't even know what to search for!).
Code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fruits = {"apple", "banana", "cabbage"};
    replaceArray(fruits);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fruits));
}

public static void replaceArray(String[] array){
    String[] animals = {"dog", "cat", "pig"};
    array = animals;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); 
}

Output
[dog, cat, pig]
[apple, banana, cabbage]

I have replaced one array with another inside a function.
When it is output within the function, the new array is shown, but then when it is printed again from the main code, the original array is shown.
This is expected as Java uses pass-by-value.
However, if I alter the code to change the array, rather than replace it, then the output changes as if it has used pass-by-reference:
Code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fruits = {"apple", "banana", "cabbage"};
    replaceArray(fruits);   
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fruits));
}

public static void replaceArray(String[] array){
    array[0] = "cat";
    array[1] = "dog";
    array[2] = "pig";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

Output:
[cat, dog, pig]
[cat, dog, pig]

Can anyone explain why it does this? Why dos it act like pass-by-value in the first example and pass-by-reference in the second?
I am aware about how java stores a pointer to objects and therefore treats objects as pass-by-reference and primitives as pass-by-value. That is not what this question is asking, I want to know why the same array is treated differently when a different way of achieving the same result is used.

I’m not sure I understand—you explicitly change array entries in the second snippet, it acts consistently ‍♂️

that is the difference between changing the content of the object vs. changing the variable referencing that object

"I am aware ... and therefore treats objects as pass-by-reference"-- not correct, objects are not treated as pass-by reference - it is a bit confusing since a pointer (reference) is indeed stored in variables and passed to the methd, but it is not the pointer/reference to the variable itself that is passed (as is some other languages) - so it is not possible for the method to change the content of the variable itself (it cannot assign a new reference to the variable used in the call)

Java is pass by value. Which means you cannot assign a new value to a passed primitive or a reference to an object and have it returned as changed via the method call. The latter may be where you are confused.

Java passes references by value.  That's not the same as pass by reference or pass by value.
